# CameraInfoManager is depreciated, what is replacing it?

Tags: ros, camera-info-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [camera_info_manager webpage](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_info_manager) says CameraInfoManager class moved to the camera_info_manager namespace. For compatibility with ROS C Turtle, the global CameraInfoManager class name is still supported. It is deprecated in Electric Emys and will be removed in Fuerte.

Is this just a name change or is something different replacing it?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10812/camerainfomanager-is-depreciated,-what-is-replacing-it?/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2011-08-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's just the rename to camera_info_manager::CameraInfoManager from CameraInfoManager.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2